# Square matrix: implicit choice of the basis

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, change-of-basis

I have encountered the discussion about similar matrices in Apostol calculus 2, and how eigenvalues are defined for the linear transformation $T: V \rightarrow V$ itself, and not for its matrix representation (call it $A = m(T)$). Thus, it holds that all representations of $T$ have the same eigenvalues, but the form of the matrix $A$ changes depending on a basis chosen for $V$.

Now I am a little bit confused. When Apostol derives the results, if need be, he always states the bases of the matrices. Moreover, in all the theorems, it is implicitly assumed that if $T: V \rightarrow W$, and $V = W$, then the selected basis of both $V$ and $W$ is the same.

But in real life, when I encounter matrices (in linear regression for example), what are their bases? Is it unit vectors of $V_n$? Or is it something else?

Is it customary to use the domain and co-domain of a transformation to be $V_n$ and $V_m$ IRL, or can it be viewed somehow else? After all when the matrix is given in engineering applications/statistics, nothing is stated about its domain/co-domain, or its selected bases.

Why am I supposed to think, that if I have a square matrix in one of my applications, the selected base for its range $T(V) \subseteq W$ is the same as the selected basis of its domain $V$? For example, why do we think that the identity matrix \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0\\
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
represents an identity transformation, when the identity could easily be 
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1\\
1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
if we just had a basis in $\{(1, 0), (0, 1)\} \subset V_2$, and a basis $\{(0, 1), (1, 0)\} \subset W_2$ for $I:V_2 \rightarrow W_2, V_2 = W_2$?

Comment: The identity matrix is the same regardless of what basis you use.

Comment: @CyclotomicField, I do not think so: I just gave an example above. Everything you need is just to swap the order of basis vectors in the domain or the range.

Comment: Your thoughts and example are both incorrect, that's what I'm telling you. A change of basis on any matrix $A$ is of the form $XAX^{-1}$ for some invertible matrix $X$ and if you put the identity matrix in for $A$ then you get $XIX^{-1}=I$. So however you've convinced yourself otherwise is the source of your confusion.

Comment: @CyclotomicField, your example with similar matrices is not contradicting what I wrote. If you have an identity matrix as in my question (with reverse entries), your X matrix would also have a reverse basis for its range, so the result will give out I as you mention, but it will be the second matrix I mentioned, not the common identity matrix.

Comment: @CyclotomicField, actually, you can't even multiply matrices in your example with similar matrices, since the bases of the range and the domain are different, so matrix multiplication is not defined the way you do it above $XIX^{-1}$. You have to do it component-wise, or swap columns in I. In the end, your result will be still the identity transformation presented as $1 - I$.

Comment: Are you not familiar with a change of basis transformation being of the form $XAX^{-1}$? It's the motivation for defining similar matrices in the first place. The matrix you've presented as the identity with rows swapped is the change of basis matrix $X$, not the identity matrix.

Comment: @CyclotomicField, no, it is the matrix representation of identity transformation. I am not sure if I can call it identity matrix, or not. But it represents the identity transformation with a different basis. Moreover, you simply cannot multiply $XI$ in this case, since your row basis and column basis are different. The identity matrix I will NOT be the traditional matrix $I$ (traditional $I$ has basis $(1, 0), (0, 1)$ and the one present has the basis $(0, 1), (1, 0)$: the order of basis elements is different).

Comment: @CyclotomicField, I am familiar with basis transformation. But it has an assumption that the basis of the transformation, the square matrix represents, is THE SAME FOR BOTH THE DOMAIN AND THE RANGE. So the basis change theorem does not hold for my example. Moreover, matrix multiplication for square matrices in a traditional sense also does not hold.

Comment: I already proved the identity matrix has the same representation regardless of the basis you choose. The permutation matrix you presented is never the identity with respect to any basis. I don't know how you've concluded it can be seen that way.

Comment: @CyclotomicField you did not prove it, because the change of basis depends on the assumption of the same basis for the range and for the domain. If this assumption does not hold, as in the case of another identity transformation representation, then your statement $XIX^{-1}$ is not correct.

Comment: I can't make you accept the truth John but your confusion isn't going to disappear until you do.

Comment: @CyclotomicField, thx for help :) was just trying to convey my point :) But still dont see it :)

Comment: @CyclotomicField You two have been talking past each other. You’re assuming the usual convention of using the same basis for the domain and codomain of an endomorphism when representing it as a matrix, but that’s not a given in the question. In fact, the last part of the question asks why one should assume that convention in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

I think here is enough to show that once you defined the associated matrix to an endomorphism $T$ respect to a choosen basis $\mathcal{B}$ of $V$,and the determinant of the endomorphism $\mbox{det}(T) := \mbox{Det}(M_{\mathcal{B}}(T)$) we convince ourselves that the characteristical polynomial of the endomorphism, defined as $p_{T}(t) := \mbox{Det}(M_{\mathcal{B}}(T)-tI_{d})$ is well defined; Once said that, if the characteristical polynomial doesn't change for change of basis (sorry about that), the eigenvalues, which are the roots of $p_{T}(t)$ won't change as well in other basis, and they will be well define as roots of $p_{T}(t)$ in every basis of $V$.

Now, what happens if we take $\mathcal{B'} \ne \mathcal{B}$ as a basis ? How $M_{\mathcal{B'}}(T)$ is related with $M_{\mathcal{B}}(T)$ ? You can prove that given the coordinates with respect to a basis it exists a unique invertible matrix $P$ (Hence, associated to an isomorphism) such that $[v]_{\mathcal{B}} = P[v]_{\mathcal{B'}}$ (where $[v]_{\mathcal{B}}$ denotes the coordinates of $v \in V$, respect to the basis $\mathcal{B}$). So if we remember of the change of basis matrix was built we have that $[]_{\mathcal{B}}^{-1} \circ M_{\mathcal{B}} \circ []_{\mathcal{B}} = (P\circ[]_{\mathcal{B'}})^{-1} \circ M_{\mathcal{B}} \circ (P\circ[]_{\mathcal{B'}})= []_{\mathcal{B'}}^{-1} P^{-1}\circ M_{\mathcal{B}} \circ P \circ []_{\mathcal{B'}} = []_{\mathcal{B'}}^{-1} M_{\mathcal{B'}} \circ []_{\mathcal{B'}}$

So what we discover whow $M_{\mathcal{B'}}$ changes in a new basis $\mathcal{B'}$, precisely as $M_{\mathcal{B}} = P^{-1}\circ M_{\mathcal{B'}} \circ P$.

Once notice this if we go back to our problem, in the new basis $\mathcal{B'}$, we have 
$$P_{T,\mathcal{B'}}(t) = \mbox{Det}(M_{\mathcal{B'}}(T)-tI_{d}) = \mbox{Det}(P^{-1}M_{\mathcal{B}}(T)P-tI_{d}) = \mbox{Det}(P^{-1}M_{\mathcal{B}}(T)P-tP^{-1}I_{d}P) = \mbox{Det}(P^{-1}(M_{\mathcal{B}}(T)-tI_{d})P) = \mbox{Det}(P^{-1})\mbox{Det}(M_{\mathcal{B}}(T)-tI_{d}) \mbox{Det}(P)$$ $$=\mbox{Det}(P)^{-1}\mbox{Det}(M_{\mathcal{B}}(T)-tI_{d}) \mbox{Det}(P) = \mbox{Det}(M_{\mathcal{B}}(T)) = P_{T,\mathcal{B}}(t)$$

Comment: Thx, but it does not answer my question :) I have this result proven in chapter 4 of Apostol calculus text. But I would like to understand how I can understand which basis is used IF I do not know the transformation, but only have its matrix.

Comment: In general, unless otherwise specified the basis choosen are the [standard basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_basis)

Comment: this is the gist of my question, I guess... So, every time we encounter any matrix in applications, it is gonna be with standard basis?

Comment: @John Yes, for both the “input” and “output” bases, unless something says otherwise. Also, for the matrix of an endomorphism, you’ll almost never see a different basis used for the “input” and “output.”

Comment: @amd, thx, i think this is the main point I was wondering about. It would be interesting, if there are any particular engineering/practical problems, where this assumption is violated? Would it even be useful to change standard bases for any problem?

Comment: @John For Linear Algebra problems for istance, of course, an accurate choice of basis can give a easier rappresentative matrix. Easier in the sense that is easier to calculate characteristical polynomial, rank, dimension of Kernel, etc...